# Custom script for custom attribute not running

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I have created a script to update a custom attribute for all of my products and for some reason it isn't running. I have it located in the base folder of magento and I'm calling it using (base siteurl)/fitment.php and it's not executing. I've tested another script using echo and it works. Are there restrictions on reading a file from the base url or something?  The file in question is below.

```
     require_once('app/Mage.php');
     umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $path =  Mage::getBaseDir('var') . '/import/YMM.csv';
    $myfile = fopen($path, "r") or die(Mage::log("failed to open" . $path));

    if ($myfile) {
    $sku = array();
    while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
        try {
            //split file by comma
            $array = explode(",", $line);
            $count = 0;
            $yearMakeModel = array();
            $make = "";
            $model = "";
            foreach ($array as $ymm) {
                if ($count == 1) {
                    $make = $ymm;
                } elseif ($count == 2) {
                    $model = $ymm;
                } elseif ($count > 1) {
                    array_push($yearMakeModel, $ymm);
                }

                $count++;
            }
            sort($yearMakeModel);
            $fullText = $make . " " . $model . " ";

            $count = 1;
            $yearsText = "";
            $multiple = false;
            $set = false;
            $previous = 0;
            $lastElement = end($yearMakeModel);
            foreach ($yearMakeModel as $years) {

                if (!empty(trim($years))) {
                    if (!$set) {

                        $yearsText = $years;
                        $previous = $years;
                        $set = true;
                    } elseif ($previous + 1 == $years) {
                        if($years == $lastElement){
                            $yearsText = $yearsText . " - " . $years;
                        }
                        $previous = $years;
                        $multiple = true;
                    } else {
                        if ($multiple) {

                            $yearsText = $yearsText . " - " . $previous . ", " . $years;
                            $previous = $years;
                            $multiple = false;
                        } else {
                            $yearsText = $yearsText . ", " . $years;
                            $previous = $years;
                            $multiple = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $count++;
            }


            $fullText = $fullText . $yearsText;


            if (array_key_exists($array[0], $sku)) {
                $sku[$array[0]] = $fullText . "<br />" . $sku[$array[0]];
            } else {
                $sku[$array[0]] = $fullText;
            }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log("error updating fitment attribute field");
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * insert fitment info into the fitment attribute
     */
    try {
        while ($year = current($sku)) {
            echo key($sku) . "<br />";

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product = $product->load($product->getIdBySku(key($sku)));


            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getEntityId());

            if($product->getId()){
                $product->setData('fitment', $year)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'fitment');
            }





            next($sku);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no restriction. Try to log something right below `Mage::app('default');` and see what happens.

Comment: can you provide sample csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains multiple syntax errors: A missing closing brace, and trying to use `empty()` on the return value of `trim()`. http://phpcodechecker.com/

Your server probably has error displaying disabled (as it should). You can override that in your custom script by adding this at the beginning:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, It may help you out to install script.

http://www.appseconnect.com/magento-install-script-and-upgrade-scripts-for-your-extension/